# Why would my server not properly link to only one file on the server, but fine on all the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, file-link

I originally posted this question on the code review forum, but was directed back to StackOverflow.

One contributor said that it was a problem with my Apache/server setup, but why only is one .js file affected?  Problem described here:

I am a bit of a jQuery raven, I learn and take as needed forage about, and have no formal education, so your patience is appreciated.

I have a main issue that a jQuery plugin is not working on the server, but works locally.

I have checked for the usual oversights (having relative links not on the server, having all the required files on the server & case sensitivity issues), but it still wouldn't work.

I am not fluent in the FireFox debugging tools either, however I found a enormous anamoly which I suspect is causing the issue.

The plugin code is in it's own .js file, and in the "debugger" in firefox, when I click on the appropriate file, instead of previewing the .js file, it shows me the index PHP/HTML of the root for the domain.

For specific, real examples:

Example page where the plugin is failing: [Here](http://bcw.se/3point0/index_debug_crousel_02.html)

Here are the error messages that I get under the "Console" tab in FireFoxe's tools:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error @ http://bcw.se/3point0/js2013/imageScroller.js:1

TypeError: $(...).tinyscrollbar is not a function @ http://bcw.se/3point0/index_debug_crousel_02.html:75

Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead. @ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js:3492
```

And I presume the first two errors above are due to the anamoly and causing the failure, not directing properly to the right .js file, see screen dump below:

[image: screendump of the firefox debugger showing a funny result when linking to a .js file.]

Can anyone help and is this the right forum?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is called `ImageScroller.js` and not `imageScroller.js`. Change that and it should work. (Apache should be case sensitive)

As `imageScroller.js` doesn't exist the url gets rewritten to the index page (probably by your .htaccess RewriteRule).

And the origin of the syntax error is kinda obvious - The browser tries to parse the fetched "js" file as JavaScript. But  just isn't valid JavaScript ;).

Sincerely
Louis

Comment: OMG, I must double check to see if I was in fact dropped on my head as a child.  thanks for the proofreding!